# my trigger inserts way to many records

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
    begin
 insert into user_has_competence (user_id,competence_id)
 select u.id,c.id from competence c
 join user u on u.organization_id = c.organization_id and c.organization_id = new.organization_id;
end
```

The tables involved are the following:

```
    Table: competence
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
name    varchar(400)
organization_id int(11)
competence_type_id  int(11)
competence_category_id  int(11)


Table: user
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
username    varchar(100)
password    varchar(100)
is_active   int(11)
user_type_id    int(11)
token   varchar(445)
organization_id int(11)
title_id    int(11)
image_path  varchar(100)
division_id int(11)

    Table: user_has_competence
Columns:
user_id int(11) PK
competence_id   int(11) PK
competence_level_id int(11)
progression varchar(45)
id  int(11) AI PK
```

now i have 8 users and when i insert 64 `competence` then i end up inserting over 30k rows into `user_has_competence`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening??

To more precis it inserts 626433 rows.

Comment: You probably should show full `CREATE TRIGGER` ...

Comment: il add it to my question @fox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a user can have only one competence per organisation? If so, I'd suggest having composite PK on `user_id, competence_id, organisation_id in user_has_competence` table. ( You need to add organisation_id there). Then, you'll see errors when your trigger will try to insert duplicate values

Edit: part of the problem may be  your trigger does not include where clause for new competence_id that you just inserted, so it will add duplicates for all existing user-competence relationships

Comment: No its many competences pr organization and user has many competences

Answer (score 0):

Anyway ... a guess ...

You have trigger on insert to `user_has_competence`, which, when a row is inserted, goes and inserts some more rows into the same table, triggering yet another instance of that trigger. And this keeps going on and on. Until you run out of space. 
(that would explain why you have seen 30k rows and then 626k rows; is it more now?)

And since your primary key on `user_has_competence` is auto increment, it won't stop you from inserting otherwise duplicate rows ...

Comment: my trigger is on competence and not user has competence are you sure this is what happens?